# How to use Visual Studio theme colors in XAML file (in an vsix 2022 extension)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2022, vsix

I've had a Visual Studio extension that uses the colors whatever the theme is in the current VS instance. The extension has worked fine until the recent VS 2022 update.

I've used the style as follows:

In the UserControl:

```
xmlns:vs_shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
```

In a TextBlock:

```
Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static vs_shell:EnvironmentColors.ComboBoxDisabledTextBrushKey}}">
```

There's a [migration guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022#xaml-sharing-techniques) that says that I should remove the `xmlns:vs_shell` and `x:Static` from the XAML and just use DynamicResource instead, e.g.:

```
Foreground="{DynamicResource EnvironmentColors.ComboBoxDisabledTextBrushKey}">
```

But that generates an error

```
XDG-0001    The resource "EnvironmentColors.ComboBoxDisabledTextBrushKey" could not be resolved.
```

This is the Property I want to use and it's marked as compatible with VS2022: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.environmentcolors.comboboxdisabledtextbrushkey?view=visualstudiosdk-2022

I haven't done real WPF development in a few years, so I'm not sure where to start looking.